# Plotting timedelta vs. time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

```
           Distance Speed   Heart Rate  Pace
Timestamp               
00:00:00    5.03    2.249   138 00:07:25
00:00:09    26.33   2.575   138 00:06:28
00:00:17    47.53   2.659   139 00:06:16
00:00:25    69.52   2.687   138 00:06:12
```

I have this Data Frame and I want to plot it using `df.plot(subplots=True)`

When I plot it Distance, Speed and Heart Rate get plotted but not the Pace.
Types of the data if that helps:

```
Distance              float64
Speed                 float64
Heart Rate              int64
Pace          timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

The problem seems to be that you can't plot a timedelta vs. time.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the pace to seconds:

```
df['Pace'] = df['Pace'].dt.total_seconds()
```

If you don't want to change the original column, you can assign it to a temporary dataframe:

```
df.assign(Pace=df['Pace'].dt.total_seconds()).plot(subplots=True)
```

---

**Edit**: In order to overwrite tick labels:

First, define a formatter function

```
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import datetime

def func(x, pos):
    return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=x))
pace_format = tkr.FuncFormatter(func)
```

Second, apply it to your chart (I assume `'Pace'` is in seconds):

```
ax = df['Pace'].plot()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(pace_format);
```

When using subplots, you need to "reach" into the right `ax` object.

Comment: I have the pace originally in seconds but converted them to mm:ss because that is the only format in which the pace makes sense.

Comment: Then you should plot the seconds but overwrite the tick labels.

Comment: Could you give an example how I would overwrite the tick labels to show the pace in  mm:ss

Comment: Thanks that worked. But now the Pace is displayed as e.g 0 days 00:08:20 how would I remove the days and hours so that I have just mm:ss

Comment: I use python's datetime module instead, see my edit.